# Temporary tables using JDBC with null ResultSet

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, temp-tables

I am executing a stored procedure via standard **JDBC Connection using MS SQL Driver version 3.0**.

I have found that when I create and insert data into a temporary table the stored procedure doesn't execute properly.

The Java code won't throw a exception, but the `javax.sql.ResultSet` will be `null`.

The point of failure in the stored procedure is when I un-comment the `INSERT INTO #TBL CLM_NAME VALUES('VAL')`

When I execute the statement using **SQL Studio Manager** it executes without hassle and the data as expected.

***Has anyone come across this or know why its the case?***

***Initially I thought its because of the SQL driver and I still think it is?***

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make sure you are creating and loading the temp table and reading from it all in the same connection?

Comment: Yes, the temporary table is created from the stored procedure I created. I only call the stored procedure from the Java code, example connect.executeQuery("{procName(?)}").

Comment: Is the offending `INSERT` instruction located in the same stored procedure that creates the temporary table?

Comment: Which method do you use for calling the stored procedure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe [this will help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/67b10d74-e94f-4b58-8ee3-59ff390db1cf):

> It is recommended that if you want to use temp tables, you should not call "prepareStatement".  You can directly execute the query from the statement object.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> String sql = "select uuid, name from Component";
>
> Statement stmt = dbCon.createStatement();
> ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
> ```
>
> If you must call "prepareStatement", then you will need to create a real table and, if needed, delete the table afterwards.

Comment: Of course, if you have any parameters, you should use prepareStatement, not createStatement, or you should be very, very careful about sql injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 6):

The executeQuery() is intended to be used with queries that return a ResultSet, typically SELECT statements.

The executeUpdate() is intended for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or DDL statements that return update counts.

Both of the above (ResultSets and update counts) are considered by JDBC to be as "results". For queries that return multiple results it requires we invoke execute().

If stored procedure makes use of temp tables, probably it returns an update count first, followed by a ResultSet. You should use execute() to run query, call getMoreResults() to skip the update count and then call getResultSet() to obtain the **ResultSet you want**. The problem here is we have to do trial and error by calling getMoreResults() multiple times to fetch result set we want by calling getResultSet().

Instead of above way of trial and error, you can suppress all the extra "query results" by specifying "**SET NOCOUNT ON**".

Changes required,

1. Put your logic in SP "SPCHILD". This Stored procedure will have logic along with temp table creation.
2. Create a SP "SPPARENT" as below,

   ```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPPARENT]    @Id int = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC(' SPCHILD @Id = ' + @Id)
    END
   ```

   From parent SP "SPPARENT" you have to call your actual SP i.e. "SPCHILD".
3. From your JDBC code make a SP call to "SPPARENT".

Comment: Great answer! Also works with declare table temp tables.

Comment: Great answer! i love u!

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same issue. In order to fix this, I am going setup a trace on my sql server and see all the statements that are being executive by the MS JDBC driver before executing the actual SP call. This should help me clear things up. Unfortunately our DBA is out today so I will have to do it tomorrow with her help. I will let u know what happens and what is the fix.

Comment: I gave up and used sub query instead of temp tables or table variables.