# Unable to return a ResultSet via JDBC when SELECTing from a temp table in MS SQL 2008 using a Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored proc which creates multiple temp tables, then creates a join on the various temp tables.

If I execute the stored proc in MS SQL 2008 I am able to see the output of the resulting select clause. However when i call the stored proc via JDBC I keep getting an error saying **the Statement did not return a result set.**

I looked around a lot but couldn't find a solution, so I resorted to creating a persistent table and inserting the output of the stored proc into it.

1. Why does this happen? (*I read something that said, as the temp table is truncated as soon as the stored proc finishes executing, no result set will get returned via JDBC*)
2. Is there a way to do this without using a persistent table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar question :
[Temporary tables using JDBC with null ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728495/temporary-tables-using-jdbc-with-null-resultset)

and this is the accepted answer : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/67b10d74-e94f-4b58-8ee3-59ff390db1cf

Summary - for stored procedures returning from temporary tables, don't use a PreparedStatement, use a regular Statement instead.