# how to create temp table using jdbc java

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, temp-tables

I need to create a temp table in order to store some ids which i will process under a later query. I am receiving error

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.`

When i execute my query for the creation of #temp table inside my sql. I don't need any resultset from this execution just need to create a temporary table with records. Please guide.

Code for my main query:

```
    String queryTempTable = "SELECT TOP (2) A.Id INTO #temp\n" +
                            "FROM  SALESDM.dbo.FactSales A\n" +
                            "INNER JOIN  SALESDM2.dbo.FactSales B\n" +
                            "ON A.Id = B.Id\n" +
                            "AND (\n" +
                            " A.sysDateModified = B.sysDateModified\n" +
                            " OR A.Id = B.Id\n" +
                            " OR A.ModifiedDatetime = B.ModifiedDatetime\n" +
                            " )";


                            System.out.println(queryTempTable);

                            if (conn == null) {
                                System.out.println("Unable to create Connection");
                            } else {
                                Statement stmtTempTable = conn.createStatement();
                                stmtTempTable.executeQuery(queryTempTable);
                            }
```

Comment: Check if this answers your question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728495/temporary-tables-using-jdbc-with-null-resultset/17826631

Answer (score 2):

You should use `executeQuery` only when you are retrieving data and want a ResultSet.

If you are modifying data, then you should use `execute`:

```
stmtTempTable.execute(queryTempTable);
```

Comment: Now its not showing any error but its not creating any #temp table inside my db.

Comment: Try removing the `INTO` from the SELECT statement, and see if your query is actually returning any results to insert into the temp table.

Comment: you mean to remove "INTO #temp" ? yes its working and giving me the results which i need to dump inside the temp table.

Comment: Try adding `AS x` to the end of the query. `SELECT... INTO... FROM... AS x` and see if that works.

Comment: I think adding "AS ..." will act as an Allias but its already the main query with one SELECT clause. I tried this but it's making my query wrong. Further, I worked with creating VIEW instead of a #temp table and your suggested modification "execute()" in my code worked there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If possible create  a view using the given query? This will act as a temporary table.  And call the view later based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @RajKumar, I tried creating a view as a workaround for #temp table and it worked.