# String formatter not formatting the whole string

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a string formatter but its not working as expected..

When I print the `SQL_QUERY`, it prints only `TABLE1`, I want the overall result `"SELECT * FROM TABLE1"`

```
package mysql.first;

public class twoconstructor {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            final String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM %s ".format("TABLE1");
    }
}
```

Comment: please follow java name convention

Comment: Please keep in mind what has been said in @Pshemo's answer: *never use String.format to create sql queries*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the method in a right way :

```
 final String SQL_QUERY = String.format ("SELECT * FROM %s ","TABLE1");
```

You should have read the warnings in your IDE.

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...%29).

Note the second argument is a vararg `Object... args` , hence it compiled fine.

Answer (score 6):

I think it has to be

```
String.format("select * from %s", "TABLE 1");
```

This is due to the odd thing in java that you can run static methods against object instances so it can be confusing. Your object instance in this case is "SELECT * FROM %s " (This is one of my biggest annoyances because it causes confusion like this)

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) . The args element is varargs so it can actually take no parameters.

Comment: +1. I've just done this myself. Intellij at least warns you when you do this.

Answer (score 2):

`String.format` is static method that takes `String format, Object... args` where first argument is format, and rest is its arguments. If you want to use this method your code should look like this

```
String SQL_QUERY = String.format( "SELECT * FROM %s ", "TABLE1")
```

---

But **never use `String.format` to create sql query**. Instead to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Take a look also at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582192/1393766).