# SQL Select where timestamp column is between two timestamps

Tags: java, sql, servlets, timestamp

I'm trying to get a SQL statement to select rows where a timestamp is between two given timestamps. here is what i tried. (this is on a Java servlet, and i java timestamp objects

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE dateAvailable >= " + from.toString() + " AND dateAvailable <= " + to.toString();
```

where from and to are timestamp objects
this is giving me a syntax error when trying to prepare the statement, please help

Comment: **Side note**: This way of making a query is _extremely vulnerable_ to SQL-Injections. Use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to add values to a query instead of just concatenating them in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC has built-in types for this. Use

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
              "SELECT * FROM dates WHERE dateAvailable BETWEEN ? AND ?"); 
ps.setTimestamp(1, from);
ps.setTimestamp(2, to);
```

You specify two `?` placeholder. You can set these to your `TimeStamp` elements.

Because it might not be immediately obvious, one purpose of using `PreparedStatement` is it helps prevent SQL injection. Read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection) for more details.

---

The reason yours wasn't working is that `Timestamp#toString()` has a specific format that does not work with SQL.

Comment: +1, but I would also say _why_ it is better to use this implementation rather than building the query directly with string concatenation :)

Comment: @BackSlash Sure, added link to other question/answers.

Answer (score -1):

You gotta use DATE functions otherwise you'll get strange side effects anyhow.