# SQL query : Wrong syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I'm tring to write a query but I obtain a syntax error. I know that this error is in the query's syntax. This is the query

```
ResultSet set=statement.executeQuery("Select * from Ombrellone where PosizioneX='"+c.getX()+"',PosizioneY='"+c.getY()+"'" );
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Unrelated: you are wide open for SQL Injection. You should use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Though it is not related, it's a bigger problem than the current problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have multiple conditions on select, you must use AND, not comma.

```
ResultSet set=statement.executeQuery("Select * from Ombrellone where PosizioneX='"+c.getX()+"' and PosizioneY='"+c.getY()+"'" );
```

Side note : [Avoid using String concatination with query parameters. They causes SQL injections and try using PreparedStatement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

Though the problem in your case was basically because you used comma on your SQL query which is wrong you can use AND or OR for condition fulfillment when using WHERE clause but also
I would suggest you to use PreparedStatement over Statement.

```
String query = "Select * from Ombrellone where PosizioneX = ? and PosizioneY = ?"
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(1,c.getX());
statement.setString(2,c.getY());
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

[Refer difference between statement and preparedstatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement)

Comment: `PreparedStatement` is definitely the better choice here, however, strictly speaking, is secondary to the problem.  The problem was the use of comma instead of `and`.

Comment: @Brandon agreed but the solution should always be perfect