# SQL Injections PDO Protect

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

I have one question
In my aplication all SQL Queries are with PDO. For Example Notes:

```
<?php
   include "config.php";
   $User_Check = $_SESSION['Login_User'];
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  
     Notes = $_POST["Notes"];  
     try {
        $sql = $conn->prepare('UPDATE Accounts SET Notes = :Notes WHERE   Username  = :User_Check');
        $sql->execute(array('Notes' => $Notes, 'User_Check' => $User_Check));
        header('Location: home.php?Message=Uspesno');
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
        header('Location: home.php?Message=Greska');
     }
   }
   $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT Notes FROM Accounts WHERE Username =   :User_Check');
   $sql->execute(array('User_Check' => $User_Check));
   $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $SelectNotes = $row['Notes'];
   conn = null;
?>
```

Now I wnat to know how much is this way secure? Can anyone do SQL Injection? And do I need to add some other form of protection? Thanks!

Comment: for the most common things you are safe, but it wouldnt hurt to furter sanitize your input variables. like `$Notes = filter_var($_POST["Notes"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PDO you don't need to escape string for prevent sql injection because prepare fx do this job.

So yes your requests are secure.

Comment: Prepared statements can still be misused (string concatenation), in which case you're just as vulnerable to SQL injections as with anything else. PDO doesn't magically fix this.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the string passed to `prepare()` is static (i.e. does not contain any variables), you should be safe from SQL injections.

The important part is separating user input from your SQL statements, and you do that by having the SQL passed to `prepare()` and the user input to `execute()`.

Similar question: [How does a PreparedStatement avoid or prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)
(The question is tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java), but neither the question nor the answer are specific to Java.)