# Put string into preparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I know that using Statement and plain String is bad programming, and I need to use preparedStatement to avoid SQL Injections.
But can I create string and then put the String into preparedStatement, or is this same as using Statement ?

for example:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_ID = ?";

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setLong(1, userId);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, and I don't see how the code shown illustrates your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ps.setString`, it is not the same as using a raw `String` query. The `PreparedStatement` is guaranteed to escape characters before sending them to the database, and your query should be immune to sql injection attacks (from that `String` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the parameters given as input into your `PreparedStatement` as is instead of building your SQL commands, in such a case the following works just fine:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(`INPUT PARAMETER`);
```

If you don't abide by this, you are still VULNERABLE to SQL Injection attacks as you would be ending up concatenating strings.

Good Reads on this topic are these links:

1. [How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks)
2. http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/why-use-preparedstatement-in-java-jdbc.html
3. [How does a PreparedStatement avoid or prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)