# Inserting Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert in postgresql db date, but when I'm inserting it, I'm getting this error:

> Error occurred while INSERTING operation: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "text that i wrote" does not exist"

I don't understand what did I code wrong that, program tries to find column in values?

But when I try to output this table, it outputs without errors

WORKERDAO class

```
public static void insertWrk(String name, String post) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //Declare a INSTERT statement
        String updateStmt ="INSERT INTO worker(full_name,post)" +
                        "VALUES" +
                        "("+name+","+post+");";
    //Execute INSTERT operation
    try {
        DBUtil.dbExecuteUpdate(updateStmt);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print("Error occurred while INSTERING Operation: " + e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

DBUTIL class

```
 public static void dbExecuteUpdate(String sqlStmt) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //Declare statement as null
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        //Connect to DB
        dbConnect();
        //Create Statement
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //Run executeUpdate operation with given sql statement
        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStmt);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Проблема в выполнение executeUpdate операции : " + e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            //Close statement
            stmt.close();
        }
        //Close connection
        dbDisconnect();
    }
}
```

WorkerController Class

```
    @FXML
private void insertWorker (ActionEvent actionEvent) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            WorkerDAO.insertWrk(nameText.getText(),postCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem occurred while inserting worker " + e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please learn to use a `PreparedStatement` properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the data you're inserting:

```
String updateStmt ="INSERT INTO worker(full_name,post)" +
                        "VALUES" +
                        "("+name+","+post+");";
```

Should be:

```
String updateStmt ="INSERT INTO worker(full_name,post)" +
                        "VALUES" +
                        "('"+name+"',"'+post+'");";
```

Be aware that you're risking [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) using this method, see about using a [parameterised insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection). [This site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) lists a bit more detail.

Comment: It helps. Thanks a lot!