# Get data from database and return it in form of pojo object

Tags: java, database, jdbc, pojo

I have a method whose return type is customer which is a pojo. When I get required `customerId` from database I want to return the customer object with the corresponding data of that `customerId`. This means it has customer name, address etc. How to proceed for this?

```
public class Customer verifyCustomerId(cutomerId){
    statement = connection.createStatement();

    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select customerid from customer");

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        if (cutomerId == resultSet.getInt(1)) {

            // return data corresponding to this id in the form of object of pojo customer

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the customerId at the start of this logic or do you need to find it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Customer` object and set your attribute in it like this :

```
Customer custemer;

if (resultSet.next()) {
   customer = new Customer(resultSet.getInt("customerid"));
}

return custemer;
```

If you want to get one result you don't need to use `while(..)` you can make an `if` instead and your `query` should have a condition `"select customerid from customer where ..."` because your query can get multiple results, if you want to get a List you can use `while` like this :

```
List<Customer> listCustemer = new ArrayList<>();

while (resultSet.next()) {
   listCustemer.add(new Customer(resultSet.getInt("customerid")));
}

return listCustemer;
```

**EDIT**

You can change your constructor and sett your fields you want like name, address and ..., like this : `Customer(int id, String name, String address, ...)`

So you can use this constructor to create a new Object like so :

```
listCustemer.add(new Customer(resultSet.getInt("customerid"), 
                 resultSet.getString("name"), resultSet.getString("address"), ...));
```

Comment: Yes you are correct but I have many no of attributes in customer entity so is there any other way or i should go for this?

Comment: @payalgala you can create a constructor which take multiple values like this  `new Customer(par, par2, par2, par2, par2..)`

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. No mention of getting the other customer fields like name and address.

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL statement needs to select the data you want to get back from the database. Your current statement will return the customerId of all rows in the customer table.

Change your statement to:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select name from customer where customerId = ?");
ps.setInt(1, cutomerId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // use ResultSet to populate Customer pojo
}
```

I have selected name from the customer table here but that assumes such a column exists. Modify it to select the columns you want.

Here is a tutorial on PreparedStatements:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

And here is a reason to use them:
[How does a PreparedStatement avoid or prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything that's stopping you from fetching those details, what you have to do is to edit your QUERY that you are trying to fetch from the Database.

```
public class Customer verifyCustomerId(cutomerId){
statement = connection.createStatement();
CustomerPoJo customer;
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from customer");

while (resultSet.next()) {
    if (cutomerId == resultSet.getInt(1)) {

// Fill in the details accordingly
        String customername = resultSet.getString(2);
        String customeraddress = resultSet.getString(3);
        ...

        customer = new CustomerPoJo();
        customer.setCustomerId(customerId);
        customer.setCustomerName(customername);
        customer.setCustomerAddress(customeraddress);
        ...

    }
}
// Instead send your customer object
return customer;
}
```