# Getting "executeQuery method cannot be used for update." error in Netbeans while extracting information from database

Tags: java, derby, netbeans-8, javadb

My question is about a Java Web program which search the database and returns the list of students as per the query
The code is below:-

```
public class StudentDAO {
        public List<Student> getStudent(String s){
             List<Student> lst=new ArrayList<>();
             try{
                Context ctx =new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
                Connection con=ds.getConnection();
                Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
                ResultSet res=st.executeQuery("select * from student where "+s);
                while(res.next())
                {
                    lst.add(new Student(res.getString(1),res.getString(2),res.getString(3),res.getString(4)));               
                }
                res.close();
                con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("errrrr..."+e.getMessage());
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

Here 's' is the string containing categories based on which I want to search students.
But I'm getting the following error :-

```
errrrr...executeQuery method can not be used for update.
```

Comment: [Absolutely required reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1582161/335858). Forget about solving this specific problem. Your code has a bigger problem to solve. As far as learning the specifics goes, print `s` when you get the exception to see what happens.

Comment: You should have a look a sample CRUD examples.

Answer (score 1):

> To perform any update     executeUpdate method is used
>   executeQuery(String sql)
>   Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object.
>   
>   execute(String sql)
>   Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results.
>
> for more information have a look at 
>   [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)