# LogIn with SQL and java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, authentication

i'm try to made a simple log in sistem with java and mysql, the configuration of the db is made up, but i have an error in the SQL sintax:

```
System.out.println("SISTEM LOGIN");
    System.out.println("INSERIRE NOMEUTENTE");
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    String user= scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("INSERIRE PASSWORD");
    String pass= scan.nextLine();

    try {
        boolean log = true;
        while(log) {
        //conn db
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,pswd);
        //creaz statement
        Statement ss = c.createStatement();
        //creaz codice sql
        String sql = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE user'" + user + "' && password='" + pass+ "' ";                    
        ResultSet res = ss.executeQuery(sql);
        if(res!=null) {
            System.out.println("LOGIN");
            log = false;
        }
        else System.out.println("LOGIN FAILE");
        }
    }
```

what do you think i haven't see in the sql string?
this is the response :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ciao' && password='12'' at line 1
```

Comment: Missing = after `WHERE user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct

```
String sql = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE user'" + user + "' && password='" + pass+ "' ";
```

If you will check you have included `"' && password='" + pass+ "' ";`

but in forst part of statement  `user'" + user` here missing =

Correct query should be

```
String sql = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='" + user + "' && password='" + pass+ "' ";
```

Answer (score 2):

The following statement is wrong and should be avoided:

```
   String sql = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE user'" + user + "' && password='" + pass+ "' ";
```

String concatenation makes it vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use `preparedstatement`. Look here for an [example](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) and [here](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement) as well.

Moreover you are missing an `=` after `user` and replace `&&` with `AND`.

And as suggested by the `error`, go through the mysql manual once.

Comment: @hamidghasemi Yeah, added that as well.

Comment: another problem is using `&&` instead of `AND` , please add this to your answer too.

Comment: @hamidghasemi Yes, true.

Answer (score 2):

Your expanded SQL statement reads

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user 'ciao' && password='12'
```

That's wrong. To be valid SQL it needs to say

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = 'ciao' AND password='12'
```

@PritamBanerjee pointed out it's vulnerable to sql injection. That's dangerous.

And, this is horrendous for another reason. You should never, **ever**, store unscrambled passwords in your dbms.  If you're not sure why, visit https://haveibeenpwned.com.

The php manual has a good explanation of the right way to do it.   http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php   You should use a one-way scrambling function like bcrypt for this purpose.

Here's some decent material about doing this in Java.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java

Comment: Lament: almost a decade after the Adobe password breach, people are **still** inventing their own password validation schemes. Why? Why? Don't universities teach that it's dangerous? The internet is crawling with cybercreeps who would steal user data and sell it.

Comment: The internet is also crawling with programming tutorials which are unsafe.. Besides not all programmers are from the university

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not any issue with the && operator as mentioned in comments : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html

You just missing the = operator just after the `WHERE user` statement.

I suggest you to use "prepared statements" when injecting parameters to your sql statement for preventing sql injection ([How does a PreparedStatement avoid or prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)).

```
PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=? && password=?");
stmt.setString(1, user);
stmt.setString(2, pass);
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
```