# Dynamic variable in executeUpdate (Java)

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the following `connection`, `statement` and `executeUpdate`

```
Connection con = DBConnPool.getInstance().getConnection();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

//String str1 = "update node set compareflag=0, personalid=NULL where ipaddress='192.168.150.213'";

String str1 = "update node set compareflag=0, personalid=NULL where ipaddress='var3.getIpAddress()'";
                            stmt.executeUpdate(str1);
```

The commented out `String` line works perfectly, the other one ignores the value returned by `var3.getIpAddress()` even though that variable does contain the correct data which I use in other areas of my code.

Do I have to create a separate variable first and then equate it to `var3.getIpAddress()` ?

Any thoughts appreciated, it's probably insufficient " or " in the wrong place.

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). You can't invoke Java methods from a portion of `String` literal.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to set parameter for safe.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("update node set compareflag=0, personalid=NULL where ipaddress=?");
pstmt.setString(1,var3.getIpAddress());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: OK but you may consider using variables also for the other columns being updated.

Comment: The last line is incorrect. `pstmt.executeUpdate(str1);` invokes the method from [`Statement.executeUpdate(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-) (where `str1` is a query and the previously bound query and parameter are ignored).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Even stronger `executeUpdate(String)` on a `PreparedStatement` should always throw a `SQLException`, that is required by the JDBC specification.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with a bind parameter. Dynamically building a query leaves you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. `PreparedStatement` (when used correctly) is [immune](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1582161/2970947) to SQL Injection. It also makes the code easier to read and reason about. For example,

```
Connection con = DBConnPool.getInstance().getConnection();
String qry = "update node set compareflag=0, personalid=NULL where ipaddress=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(qry);
stmt.setString(1, var3.getIpAddress());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: OK but you may consider using variables also for the other columns being updated.

Comment: Thanks for all replies, much appreciated.

Comment: @RobertKock There is no reason to do that if those values are fixed.