# Attempt Log In 3 times in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

My Problem is that my certain code didn't decrement or increment after the first attempt it decrement by 1 but after another try it didnot decrement, Please help me this is a project. It will help me a lot. It is log in attempt if the password is correct it will go to another panel but if wrong it will not go and will warn 3 times. If the attempts are 3 times. The account will be deactivated in database.

I already try to put the declaration inside but none of it works.

```java
String x = BI.getText();
String x2 = WD.getText();
String x3 = FT.getText();
char[] pass = passtft.getPassword();
String password = new String(pass);
boolean container = false;
System.out.println(accs);
int x5 = 3;
if (isclick.equals(x)) {
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, userdb, passdb);
        String query = "select * from accounts where accountnumber = '" + accs + "' ";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String pin = rs.getString("pin");
            String saltpin = rs.getString("saltpin");
            boolean verify = PasswordUtils.verifyUserPassword(password, pin, saltpin);
            if (verify == true) {
                container = true;
            } else {
                container = false;
                x5--;
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    if (container == true) {
        PassPanel.setVisible(false);
        balancePanel.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Pin!");
        passtft.setText("");
        amountT = "";
    }
    System.out.println(x5);
    if (x5 == 0) {
        try {
            Connection cay = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, userdb, passdb);
            String qr = "update accounts set status = '" + "deactivated" + "' where accountnumber = '" + accs + "'";
            Statement rst = cay.createStatement();
            rst.executeUpdate(qr);

            cay.close();
            rst.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're card is blocked! You've reach your maximum limit! Please Contact our Customer Service !");
    }
}
```

I expected to decrement and if the attempts are 3 it will update to database.

Comment: As it isn't clear where the loop is, or how this is being called, all that one can say is that it is setting the poorly named `x5` to 3, and possibly decrementing it if verify is false. There is clearly missing driver code. Also, consider refactoring into smaller methods that are tightly focused.

Answer (score 1):

> **Suggestions:**

There is always something to be said about the benefits of good variable and object naming and **x this**, **x that**, or **x whatever** just doesn't fall into that realm. Of course you can designate whatever names you like to your objects as long as they follow those Java Rules that are **written in stone** but, for the sake of your future sanity (and that of others) it would be wise to be somewhat descriptive with your naming. It truly does help follow the code much much easier and can be extremely beneficial towards catching bugs even before the code is first run. Bottom line, your choice....I'm just sayin :o)

Leave the connection to your Database open until you know you're finished with it. There is no need to open and close it all the time for different conditions within the very same method. Utilize a **finally** block to close the objects at the end of your method.

Use **PreparedStatement**'s when using SQL strings to deal with database data. This will **help** prevent the possibility of SQL Injection and makes your SQL Strings somewhat more secure. [Read this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection) for a little more insight on the matter.

Although not absolutely mandatory and in this particular use case, I think you should try to use your **while** loop just for acquiring the data from your database. I wouldn't start jumping around to other methods and checking specific conditions where there lies the possibility of **more than one** iteration. After all, what if on a first iteration a condition is true but on a second iteration (if there is one) the same condition is false?

> **The Task At Hand:**

Because you don't disclose the home for your example code I have to assume it's contained within the event block of a **Submit** button or something similar so the example code I provide below utilizes **return** statements to exit the event method.

Instead of decrementing a login attempt instance variable counter the below example increments the counter (named: **loginAttempts**). This is done after an attempt has been made to acquire the pertinent data from database in case an error occurred during that particular process. You wouldn't want to take the chance of disabling someone's Card because of something out of his or her control.

Read the comments in code:

```
// Class Member (instance) Variables
Connection conn = null;
int loginAttempts = 0;
int maxAttemptsAllowed = 3;
String acountNum = "AB42321"; 
String customerServicePhone = "XXX-XXX-XXXX";
//===========================================================

// Local (method) Variables
PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String password = new String(passtft.getPassword());
String pin = null;
String saltpin = null;
boolean viewPanel = false;

try {
    if (isclick.equals(BI.getText())) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, userdb, passdb);
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accountnumber = ?");
        pStmt.setString(1, acountNum);
        rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            /* Check status to see if User's card was previously deactivated
               and wasn't yet reactivated by admin.   */
            String status = rs.getString("status");
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("deactivated")) {
                // Card is currently deactivated. Inform User
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><font color=red><b>Your Card has "
                        + "been previously Deactivated!</b></font><br><br>Please Contact our "
                        + "<font color=blue>Customer Service</font> at<br>Phone: " + 
                          customerServicePhone, "Card Deactivated", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                // Get out of loop (don't bother with other data).
                break;
            }
            // Status is good so get pin and saltpin
            pin = rs.getString("pin");
            saltpin = rs.getString("saltpin");
        }

        loginAttempts++;    // Increment login counter

        /* Make sure pin and saltpin actually contain something 
           and that login attempts is less than or equal to the 
           max attempts allowed.    */
        if (pin != null && saltpin != null && loginAttempts <= maxAttemptsAllowed) {
            // Check the pin for validity
            viewPanel = PasswordUtils.verifyUserPassword(password, pin, saltpin);
            //PIN Valid!
            if (viewPanel) {
                PassPanel.setVisible(false);
                balancePanel.setVisible(true);

                // TO DO: Descriptively Log the LOGIN success in a DB Login Table.

                return; // Success. Get out of this particular method or event.
            }
            else {
                // pin is INVALID!
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Wrong Pin Number Supplied!<br>"
                        + "You have <b><font color=red>" + (maxAttemptsAllowed - loginAttempts) + "</font>"
                        + "</b> attempt remaining.<br><br><font color=blue>Please try "
                        + "again...</font></html>", "Invalid PIN", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                passtft.setText("");    // Clear JPasswordField
                passtft.requestFocus(); // Set focus to JPasswordField
                amountT = "";           // Clear Amount JTextField

                // TO DO: Descriptively Log the LOGIN failure in a DB Login Table.
            }
        }

        // If code ever reaches this point then...
        // See if passwordAttempts has reached Max login attempts
        if (loginAttempts == maxAttemptsAllowed) {
            /* The Maximum number of login attempts has been processed
               with no success so, apply deactivation!   */
            pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE accounts SET status = ?"
                    + " WHERE accountnumber = ?");
            pStmt.setString(1, "Deactivated");
            pStmt.setString(2, acountNum);
            int i = pStmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(i + " Records Updated"); // Can remove

             if (i > 0) { loginAttempts = 0; } // Zero the member variable loginAttempts

            // TO DO: Descriptively Log the Deactivation in a DB Login Table.

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><font align=justify>For safety reasons "
                    + "&nbsp;<b><font color=red>your Card has been Disabled</b></font>&nbsp; "
                    + "from<br>use since you have reached your maximum login attempts!<br><br>"
                    + "Please contact our <font color=blue>Customer Service</font> to have your "
                    + "card<br>reactivated! Phone: " + customerServicePhone + "</html>", 
                    "Card Disabled", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // Inform User of an Error!
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><b><font color=red>A System Error "
        + "Has Occured!</font></b><br><br> Please contact Customer Service<br>"
        + "for assistance at: <font color=blue>" + customerServicePhone + 
        "</font></html>", "System Error!", 
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    // TO DO: Descriptively Log the Error in a DB Error Table.
}

// This finally block will always ensure 
// objects are closed if they are open.
finally {
    try {
        if (rs != null)    { rs.close();    }
        if (pStmt != null) { pStmt.close(); }
        if (conn != null)  { conn.close();  }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) { 
        // TO DO: Descriptively Log the Error in a DB Error Table.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) I forgot to comment on it :) I solved my problem because of you :)