# How to connect my servlet to the boolean method from another class?

Tags: servlets, methods, boolean

I have tried some variations and i of course imported the class which contains the boolean method i meed in my Servlet, but it doesnt see the method anyway.

this is the method in my class logIN:

````
        MyCon = Database.getConnection();
        boolean result = false;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;



        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM input_form WHERE username ='"+username+"'AND password='"+password+"'";
            statement=MyCon.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                result=true;
            }else {
                result = false;

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {



        }
        return result;


    }

} ```

And when i need to access that method in servlet, it doesnt see it :

 ```protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        response.setContentType("text/html/charset-UTF-8");
        out =response.getWriter();

        boolean login = processLogin(username,password);  //this is where it doesnt see it

         ```

what could i do for my servlet to see the method?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `object` of class which you need to call and then use that `object` to called required method.So your doPost method will look like below :

```
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    response.setContentType("text/html/charset-UTF-8");
    out =response.getWriter();
    Login l1 =new Login();//creating object of class
    boolean login = l1.processLogin(username,password); //using object to call the method
   //do further process
```

Also , use `PreparedStatement` to select value in database and to avoid any [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection) .So your method code will look like below :

```
PreparedStatement ps = MyCon.prepareStatement("select *from input_form where username=? AND password= ?");
    //setting value for "?"
    ps.setString(1, username);
    ps.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    //if true
    if (rs.next()) {
    result=true;
    }else{
     result = false;
    }
```