# how to make search bar without having to type double quotation?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, search, searchbar

hello everyone i am trying to make this search bar in java but when i search without typing double quotation i get this error

[search error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMl86.png)

but when i type numbers or words with double quotation it works just fine

[searching with double quotation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RISlf.png)

here is my code

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19E0J.png)

```
private void jButton_Show1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
      try{
          String Accounts_Choose_Value = jTextField1.getText();
          // Accounts_Choose_Value = (String) Accounts_jComboBox_Choose_Value.getSelectedItem();
                  
          if(Accounts_Choose_Value.equals(Accounts_Choose_Value)){
              String sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE URL="+Accounts_Choose_Value;
        con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/accountmanagerdb","root","");
              Statement s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
              ResultSet rs =s.executeQuery(sql);
              if(rs.next()){
                  String Account_User_Name =rs.getString(2);
                  String Account_Email =rs.getString(3);
                  String Account_Password =rs.getString(4);
                  String Account_Backup_Codes =rs.getString(5);
                  
                  jLabel_Account_User_Name.setText(Account_User_Name);
                  jLabel_Account_Email.setText(Account_Email);
                  jLabel_Account_Password.setText(Account_Password);
                  jLabel_Account_Backup_Codes.setText(Account_Backup_Codes);
              }
          }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex,
                            "Database",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
      
      }
      
    }
```

ididn't wirte anything in the textfield

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change this one line But beware of [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE URL=\""+Accounts_Choose_Value+"\"";
```

Basically you need to wrap the where clause entry in double quotes your first query generates

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE URL=google
```

Which means you are asking give me all rows which have column value `URL` equal to column value `google`

The right query is

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE URL="google"
```

Now you are asking give me all rows whose URL is equal to "google" string

In the first case your code fails saying I cant find a column named google

**EDIT**

Basically you should not directly string interpolate your variables that will lead to security issues

You can refer how to do prepared statement here

[Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Don’t do that! Read about SQL injection, then start using a PreparedStatement for this.

Comment: But please use bind variables, otherwise this is open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Axel Updated the Answer with the warning, My bad I should have been careful with my answers

Comment: can someone please explain how to prevent sql injection in my code

Comment: @Yahya: It's simple. Don't ever put together SQL queries from user input. Create a PreparedStatement and then set the parameter values using the setXXX-methods. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582192/341291) to another question for an example of what could go wrong. Read more about PreparedStaement in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-statement-preparedstatement) by Baeldung.

Comment: @k4vin Maybe you should edit your answer into an example explaining concatenating user input into SQL statements is dangerous and show how change OP's code into one that uses PreparedStatement instead to turn down- into upvotes. ;-)